# Insert number to a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, insertion

I have an ordered dictionary like following:

```
source =([('a',[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,11,13,17]),('b',[1,2,3,12])])
```

I want to calculate the length of each key's value first, then calculate the `sqrt` of it, say it is **L**.

Insert **L** to the positions which can be divided without remainder and insert "1" after other number.

For example, `source['a'] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,11,13,17]` the length of it is 9.
Thus sqrt of `len(source['a'])` is 3.

Insert number 3 at the position which can be divided exactly by 3 (eg. position 3, position 6, position 9) if the position of the number can not be divided exactly by 3 then insert 1 after it.

To get a result like folloing:

```
result=([('a',["1,1","2,1","3,3","4,1","5,1","6,3","7,1","11,1","13,3","10,1"]),('b',["1,1","2,2","3,1","12,2"])]
```

I dont know how to change the item in the list to a string pair. BTW, this is not my homework assignment, I was trying to build a boolean retrival engine, the source data is too big, so I just created a simple sample here to explain what I want to achive :)

Comment: If this is a standard Python dictionary, then it is not ordered. You need to use collections.OrderedDict (maybe you do?).

Comment: It's always a good idea to show us what you tried or what you think might solve the problem, even if completely wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this seems to be a homework, I will try to help you with the part you are facing problem with

> I dont know how to change the item in the list to a string pair.

As the entire list needs to be updated, its better to recreate it rather than update it in place, though its possible as lists are mutable

Consider a list

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

to convert it to a list of strings, you can use list comprehension

```
lst = [str(e) for e in lst]
```

You may also use built-in `map` as `map(str,lst)`, but you need to remember than in Py3.X, map returns a map object, so it needs to be handled accordingly

Condition in a comprehension is best expressed as a conditional statement

```
<TRUE-STATEMENT> if <condition> else <FALSE-STATEMENT>
```

To get the index of any item in a list, your best bet is to use the built-in [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate)

If you need to create a formatted string expression from a sequence of items, its suggested to use the [format string specifier](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

```
"{},{}".format(a,b)
```

The length of any sequence including a `list` can be calculated through the built-in [len](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len)

You can use the operator `**` with fractional power or use the `math` module and invoke the `sqrt` function to calculate the square-root

Now you just have to combine each of the above suggestion to solve your problem.